# Many to Many relationship in Entity Framework Core User, Team , Idea

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to define many to many relationship between three entity,
User, Idea, Team

an Idea can have many Teams,
an Idea can have many users associated as visibility,
an Idea will have a single user as creator
a Team can have many users,
a User can be in many team,
a User can create many Idea

Below is the models

```
public class Idea
{
    public Idea() {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
        Teams = new HashSet<Team>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public Team() {
        TeamUsers = new HashSet<User>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> TeamUsers { get; set; }
    
}

 public class User
{
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Even after trying too many article , I am not able to achieve this , Can someone please help

Comment: Start with an ERD, rather than writing code. Much easier to model relationships.

Comment: " I am not able to achieve this" what's the problem?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , when I am defining the Model as above , it make User and Idea one to one mapping, Can you suggest how I can adjust the model the scenario I mention in my question